# Minimum file permissions to delete a file

Tags: files, permissions, rm

To delete a file in Linux:

What minimal permissions do we need to set on it?

What minimal permissions do we need to set on its parent directory?

Comment: you need write (+w) permissions, and parent directory should be accessible (+x) to the user which is you want to have delete permission.

Comment: Permissions on the file itself don't matter.  You need +wx on the parent directory.

Answer (score 9):

If you try to delete a file then the normal file permissions (including ACL and RichACL) do not matter at all. The only relevant attribute to the file itself is the file system attribute `immutable`, see `man lsattr`, `man chattr`.

You need write permission for the direct parent directory and execute permission for all parent directories.